# How to add amgraph in update chart in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I want to show multiple line graphs in stepline amchart. But the issue is 
   for one response , I need to show one Line graph only, for the same chart for 
   another response I need to show 2 line graphs.

```
     this.timeChart = this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 80,
  "autoMarginOffset": 20,
  "marginTop": 7,
  "dataProvider": chartData,
"valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Response Count",
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "gridCount": 5,
    "gridAlpha": 0
}],
"graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]<br>[[category]]<br><b>[[value]] </b>",
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "bullet": "square",
    "type": "step",
    "bulletAlpha": 0,
    "bulletSize": 4,
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0,
    "valueField": "members",
    'lineColor': 'pink',
    'title': 'Member Response',
},
```

After this I want to add another graph object in Update Chart.
How to do that.

Comment: Is this using the angular plugin or regular JS?

Comment: this is in angular6 project with installing of @amcharts/amcharts3

Comment: `updateChart` allows you to specify a callback to modify the chart object as you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2/#user-content-how-to-use). The chart's graphs are found in the `graphs` property (`this.timeChart.graphs`). You can modify the array by using array methods to add a new graph object similar to the config passed in makeChart (`this.timeChart.graphs.push({/* graph object config*})`) or use array methods to remove a graph.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In another way we can show or hide graphs with showGraph() method and hideGraph() methods